# How to simultaneously execute scripts in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop

I want to run a lot of scripts simultaneously in a bash script, with a for-loop.
Example code:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=0
for a in (0..255)
do
  ./rleit.sh $a > res/$a.txt
done
```

I tried this with and without a `.` after the `./rleit.sh $a > res/$a.txt` line. Also putting `exec` before that line does not run the scripts simultaneously.

Comment: Put a `&` at the end of the line

Comment: `(0..255)` → `{0..255}`